# RelaxNG enumerated element names

Tags: xml, relaxng

If I have element names that must look like this:

```
<myElem>
  <subElem_n/>
  <subElem_n+1/>
  <subElem_n+2/>
</myElem>
```

Where 'n' = 0;

How would I enforce this is RelaxNG?

The tricky part is the dynamically generated element names.

Comment: Can't find a way to add patterns to name classes. Can't impose ordering on name classes either.

Answer (score 1):

**Concerning your XML sample file :**

The XML you provide is not well formed. The `+` is not allowed in XML names. [See here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-qualnames), have a look at `PrefixedName` and `UnprefixedName` to have precise syntax.

**Concerning your validation case :**

As far as I know, you can't add dynamically generated validation rules on element names with Relax NG.

The only way to check this kind of structure is to use either ISO Schematron or the upcoming XML Schema 1.1 recommandation with the `xs:assert` element.

Those two solutions use XPath and you can check the names with the `local-name()` function.

**One more thing**

Be aware that it's not always considered a good practice to have such structure, you can also consider this kind :

```
<myElem>
    <subElem rank="1"/>
    <subElem rank="2"/>
    <subElem rank="3"/>
    ...
</myElem>
```