# How to use a pattern to match element names in compact relaxng

Tags: relaxng, relaxng-compact

I have some XML that needs validating from external source that has a similar layout too below

```
<stuff>
   <id-0001>test</id-0001>
   <id-0002>test</id-0002>
   <id-0003>test</id-0003>
   <id-0004>test</id-0004>
</stuff>
```

I tried the following but it is not valid

```
datatypes xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"
start = stuff

stuff = element stuff
{
   element id-* { text }*
}
```

Ideally I would like a regex match on the id tag names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [relax-ng compact: attribute whose name matches a reg-ex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854390/relax-ng-compact-attribute-whose-name-matches-a-reg-ex)

Comment: Attributes are not elements - so it is not a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge it's not possible to define patterns in RELAX NG for element names. See also [RelaxNG enumerated element names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247467/relaxng-enumerated-element-names) and [relax-ng compact: attribute whose name matches a reg-ex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854390/relax-ng-compact-attribute-whose-name-matches-a-reg-ex/16856734#16856734) for similar questions.

Comment: When a question is a duplicate of another question, like this one is a duplicate of [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854390/relax-ng-compact-attribute-whose-name-matches-a-reg-ex/16856734#16856734) that you point out in your answer, the thing to do is to vote to close the question as a duplicate, or flag to close.